# I have MAC M1 pro chipset and when Im running test in android studio Im getting error which is attached below.Im able to build and app is running fine

Tags: android, android-studio, apple-m1

so I have MAC M1 pro chipset and when Im running test in android studio I'm getting error which is attached below , I'm able to build and app is running fine.

```
com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteException: [-91] cannot load library: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:  dlopen(/private/var/folders/66/7nxvb30d67ddp3llcg4wqrw80000gq/T/1663693890027-0/libsqlite4java.dylib, 0x0001): tried: 

(fat file, but missing compatible architecture (have (i386,x86_64), need (arm64e)))
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteException: [-91] cannot load library: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /private/var/folders/66/7nxvb30d67ddp3llcg4wqrw80000gq/T/1663693890027-0/libsqlite4java.dylib: dlopen(/private/var/folders/66/7nxvb30d67ddp3llcg4wqrw80000gq/T/1663693890027-0/libsqlite4java.dylib, 0x0001): tried: '/private/var/folders/66/7nxvb30d67ddp3llcg4wqrw80000gq/T/1663693890027-0/libsqlite4java.dylib' 

(fat file, but missing compatible architecture (have (i386,x86_64), need (arm64e)))
at org.robolectric.shadows.util.SQLiteLibraryLoader.loadFromDirectory(SQLiteLibraryLoader.java:90)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.util.SQLiteLibraryLoader.doLoad(SQLiteLibraryLoader.java:57)
```

Comment: Which version of robolectric do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [Apple Silicon support issue](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/6311)

Maybe you could upgrade robolectric to 4.7.0+.

in build.gradle

```
testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:4.8.1"
```

Comment: Now I m getting this error and i have enablejetifier = true
Failed to transform '/Users/name/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.68/46a080368d/bcprov-jdk15on-1.68.jar' using Jetifier. Reason: IllegalArgumentException, message: Unsupported class file major version 59

Comment: and if I do enable jetifier = false ,

I get not able to merge android manifest.xml file
Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [androidx.core:core:1.5.0] AndroidManifest.xml:24:18-86
 is also present at [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory).
 Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:72:5-552:19 to override.

Comment: Did you try [this](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/issues/762#issuecomment-852056041) with ```enablejetifier = true``` ?